# Share Index across multiple site

Tags: sxa, solr, sitecore-client, sxa-search

We are using SXA to build 4 sites under same talent for example site A , B , C and D.
We have requirement to show the news articles created under any of these sites to be shown to rest of the sites , example when site A has news it should be showing in Site B , C and D , when clicking on any new article related to site A it should redirect site A URL ex : https://www.A.com

We have are using SXA site grouping to create index / site to make the crawling content of this site is faster , however we cant share news article as per screenshots

We need to shared index for news articles across all sites , having multiple roots as described below
https://www.searchstax.com/docs/searchstudio/multi-root-crawling/

so is there a way to have shared index for all news and configure SXA site grouping to check news from this index file ?

Comment: I think you should configure it the other way around and include news from all sites into each index. Otherwise you won't be able to fetch content from "shared" index if you are using siteAindex or siteBindex - unless you customize code heavily
Anyway I think that having one index is the best - this way you don't have to restart instance after deployment and you can configure everything in SXA 
https://doc.sitecore.com/en/users/sxa/93/sitecore-experience-accelerator/extend-search.html#extend-search-to-include-other-sites

Answer (score 0):

In that case, you can define your index's root to your tenant instead of the site, then make sure you only index whatever you need and is strictly necessary (templates/field) to avoid ending up with a huge index.

I hope it helps you.